# jquery datepicker datepicker beforeShowDay not working in next year

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i am trying to enable dates in jQuery datepicker calendar, it works well for 2013 dates but 2014 dates it is not working.

here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var enabledDays = ['11-30-2013', '12-14-2013', '12-21-2013', '01-11-2014', '01-11-2014', '01-25-2014', '02-08-2014', '02-22-2014', ]

        function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
            var m = date.getMonth(),
                d = date.getDate(),
                y = date.getFullYear();
            for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, enabledDays) != -1) {
                    return [true];
                }
            }
            return [false];
        }
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
    });
});
</script>
```

how to get this to work in 2014 dates aswell. 
Thanks

Comment: any idea guys, where could be the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 2):

Might be too late to help, but drop the leading zero on months <=9. 03-10-2014 fails whereas 3-10-2014 works fine with the code you have. See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/79p6z/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var enabledDays = ['11-30-2013', '12-14-2013', '12-21-2013', '3-10-2014', '11-30-2014']

    function enableAllTheseDays(date) {
        var m = date.getMonth(),
            d = date.getDate(),
            y = date.getFullYear();
        for (i = 0; i < enabledDays.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, enabledDays) != -1) {
                return [true];
            }
        }
        return [false];
    }

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        beforeShowDay: enableAllTheseDays
    });
});
```